# "I like to drink tea" and "I like drinking tea" - do constructions "like to verb" and "like verb + ing" have any difference?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

What is a difference between these two sentances?

> I like to drink tea. 
> I like drinking tea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["like to" vs "like"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326134/like-to-vs-like) (There's not much difference, although the -ing form more strongly indicates pleasure in the activity itself, rather than thinking it's a good idea or enjoying its consequences - "I like to drink tea every morning because I believe it promotes health and long life, although I don't like the taste").

Comment: If the question needs an answer, @StuartF has it. In Spanish, they are identical.

Comment: Just to be clear, before posting a question, one should search to see if it’s already been asked. And searching right here in ELL is only one variety of investigation one should do to try to find the answer on one’s own before posting a question.